# Stacking c# class property attributes for XML serialization

Tags: c#, xml

I am using XmlSerializer to convert a piece of XML into a C# object. One property of the xml object is giving me trouble.

```
<Description Long="long description" Warranry="detail about warranty" Short="shorter description"/>
```

Rather than representing this exactly as it is by creating a description object, I want to make it cleaner and make properties for each of the attributes in the Description node and make them part of the root object. I know how to access this data, but I cant figure out how to do it. Logically I would have thought that I could just stack the attributes above the property to achieve what I want (see the code below) but VS doesn't allow it.

```
public class Test
{
  [XmlElement("Description")]
  [XmlAttribute("Long")]
  public string LongDescription {get; set;}
  public string ShortDescription {get; set;}
  public string WarrantyInfo {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what you can do and how you do it? The two `Attribute`s (`[XmlElement("Description")]` and `[XmlAttribute("Long")]`) are only applied to the next element (here, the `LongDescription` Property). So i guess when you de/serialize it, only the `LongDescription` is working, correct?

Comment: You'll need a separate `Description` class to hold these unless you want to manually write the serialisation code.